# Can't read SMS on android

Tags: java, android, permissions, sms

I can't seem to get a basic sms reading app to work on android. Not sure what am I missing here. I think I have all the basic minimum specified in the code, despite that it seems to be not working. The `onReceive()` of `SmsReceiver` is never invoked. All the required permissions are set.

Here are my files.

`MainActivity.java`

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    //...
    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        requestReadAndSendSmsPermission();

        smsReceiver = new SmsReceiver() {
            @Override
            protected void onData(String data) {
                  //handle
            }   
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        //intentFilter.setPriority(999);
        registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
    }

    private void requestReadAndSendSmsPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE}, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE}, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE}, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 1);
    }

    //...
    //...
}
```

`SmsReceiver.java`

```java
public abstract class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "SmsReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (context == null || intent == null) {
            return;
        }
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (!action.equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {
            return;
        }

        //read sms      

        onData("sms received");
    }

    protected abstract void onData(String data);
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mysmsapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MySMSApp">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing defining the receiver entry in AndroidManifest.xml file for your `BroadcastReceiver` named `SmsReceiver` please make the entry for it else OS will not know if you have a broadcast receiver waiting to be triggered.

Depending upon what is your use case it might be something like

```
<receiver
    android:name=".SmsReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Or

```
<receiver
    android:name=". SmsReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Note:** These receiver are sample receiver please use the correct one as per your use case, the main point is you are missing receiver entry in your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

i use this code to read incoming message

```
    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static final Uri smsuri = Apconsts.smsuri;
        private static final String pdu_type = "pdus";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            // Get the SMS message.
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs;
            String format = bundle.getString("format");
            // Retrieve the SMS message received.
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get(pdu_type);
            String body="";String adrs="";
            if (pdus != null) {
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++){
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){ msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]); }
                    else{ msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], format); }
                    adrs=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    body += ""+msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                }
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The message Body: "+body+"\nThe address: "+adrs, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          }
    }
```

and this receiver in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I tried extactly this and still not working.

Comment: My phone is not being detected, so I use Toast api to debug. Android is definitely a mess to work with. :( :(

Comment: what you want exactly , just read a message or handle all messages like messaging app

Comment: I just want to listen on the latest sms and send that sms to the main activity to display. That's it. This is only for educational purpose.

Comment: any updates, have you solve your problem?